# Custom flag for (somewhat) copied, bad quality answer declined

Tags: discussion, answers, declined-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25391732/4230591):

> It is a duplicate of the accepted answer. Used the same module, just a
>   different object in it. – user 5061 yesterday

and it was declined:

> declined - a moderator
>   reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Although I do understand that it is not an *exact* copy of the accepted answer, there are some serious, in my opinion, issues.

**Firstly,** it uses the same approach to the problem. It uses `string` module which has those 4 objects:

```
>>> s.uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> s.ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> s.lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> s.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

What if I use loops or list comprehensions to create a somewhat different representation of the objects? Does that make it "different" in a useful way? Because thats exactly what the flagged answer does.

It uses the same approach as the accepted (`string` module), and on top of that it doesn't show how to solve the problem in the question.

Even if it were not a duplicate (which in my opinion it is), it's still pure noise which came 1 year after the original answer.

---

**Question:**
-Was the flag decline justified?
-Should I take other actions than custom flagging content like that? (I did downvote and comment, but apparently this user is never coming back)

---

**UPDATE**:
And now that answer is deleted.

Comment: There isn't any point in flagging the question when you have a beef with an answer.  Just downvote a poor answer, a moderator isn't going to judge the technical merit of it.

Comment: @HansPassant I dont have a beef with the answer. I dont think there is anything to change. I only think it should be removed. It paraphrases a part of the accepted answer, and additionally **adds nothing of value**. It's pure noise.

Comment: related: [Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/165773)

Answer (score 7):

Those answers are different enough that it's not obvious to someone who isn't a Python programmer that they're the same. Don't ask moderators to make a technical determination like that. I know at least one of them is a Python expert, but you can't flag things with the expectation that they'll be handled by a domain expert.

This is a situation that doesn't need moderator intervention. Downvoting and commenting is enough. That answer existing doesn't hurt anything, so it doesn't need to be deleted.

Comment: So i should only flag answers that are *clearly* copy pasted? Also, i disagree that it doesn't hurt. Noise hurts (e.g. formalities). If i had simply downvoted, without asking in python chat (which got more downvotes on the answer), it would have a total of +1. That would make others read it too and waste their time.

Comment: @user5061 Yes, only flag answers to be deleted if they're clearly copy/pasted much later. No, noise like this does not hurt anything. That answer is still about 100 votes away from the accepted one, so it's never going to rise up the page. Stack Overflow was designed to deal with this.

Comment: "Don't ask moderators to make a technical determination like that." - Don't they skip flags they cant determine so that  some other mod handles it?

Comment: @user5061: They generally decline flags that require them to have knowledge of a certain programming language. We can't expect moderators to dive into the technicalities of every flagged question / answer.

Comment: @user5061 No. 1) There might not be *any* mod that is a domain expert in that subject, particularly in niche topics 2) Even if there is one or two, they're still unlikely to be able to judge posts on their technical merits as well as the entirety of that community can, in aggregate, and the mod's decision couldn't be undone if others disagreed with the decision 3) Mods already have more work needing to be done than they can do, so trying to handle flags like this would push their workload *way* beyond what they can get done; the community handling issues like this is how SO scales.

Comment: @Servy 1 and 3 are ok as arguments, but i highly doubt 2 is true. Their actions *can* be undone, and some cases arent noticed until someone brings some attention to them (like the flagged answer having positive score, until i noticed it). With 1 and 2 I would have accepted Bill's answer if it didnt include the incorrect "doesn't hurt anything", because it does. Noise hurts and it gets removed from SO on a daily basis.

Comment: @user5061 It could only be undone by another mod; it couldn't be undone by the community, and most of the community members wouldn't even be able to see it to realize if the mod had incorrectly deleted it.  Moderators aren't elected to their positions because they're the best technical experts in their communities; they're elected because they're more intimately aware with how the site handles moderation of content (irrespective of technical merit) and are willing to spend time cleaning the site up.  There's no basis for thinking they're going to have stronger technical knowledge than others.